# Advice needed on publishing a textbook!

Tags: publications, open-access, medicine

I have authored a large textbook on Male Pattern Baldness already in 2015 in my native language, Greek,
I have finished the translation in English and looking for a publisher.
It is a unique medical textbook, addressing multiple disciplines in a very detailed manner.
Springer has been interested in publishing my work but does not offer remuneration per chapter download, which is the most distinctive aspect of my book since there are 129 dedicated chapters for each separate issue!
I am interested more in "fame" than "fortune" but knowing that most of the revenue from my work will be generated in a way that I get no remuneration at all will be at least annoying.

Can anyone suggest any other reputable publishing house that is offering a fee -per-chapter download as well?
Can anyone suggest a house that can guarantee visibility and spread of my work as good as Springer?
If making ay considerable money out of this huge work is not possible, would you suggest Open Access for increased visibility?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your current publisher should be able to give you suggestions/use their contacts...

Answer (score 2):

Industry standard here is to offer royalties based off the revenue made. If Springer is selling your book, then each chapter download should not be free, and some percentage of that revenue goes to you.

I'd be surprised if anyone is willing to offer you remuneration based on *downloads*, since the same buyer might download the book several times.

Comment: The chapters downloadable at Springer's website are not free but there is no percentage revenue for the author. Do you have any suggestions for the other 2 questions?

Comment: @KonstantinosAnastassakis is this your website? https://hairclinicgreece.com/dr-anastassakis/ If so I'll ask an acquisition editor from a publisher I know to contact you.

Comment: Yes this is mine, thank you! which house is he working for if I may ask?

Comment: @KonstantinosAnastassakis I asked World Scientific, did you get an email from them? If you don't want to publish with them I can ask another publisher too.