# What is the academic argument against Sci-Hub?

Tags: publications, publishers, literature, sci-hub

I know that some consider certain activities of Sci-hub to violate the law in some jurisdictions. Many of the previous questions and opinions related to Sci-hub have focused on these legal aspects (and they are certainly important to consider).

However, I am wondering what are the main harms or downsides associated with the existence of Sci-hub and similar services from the perspective of academics, researchers, and students. I am asking because this topic is relatively new to me, and I would like to better understand the main cons of Sci-hub as perceived by fellow academics (as opposed to publishers or lawyers).

Comment: Some interesting background info, by the way: https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/04/whos-downloading-pirated-papers-everyone

Answer (score 21):

> What is the academic argument against Sci-Hub?

There are none.  The arguments against sci-hub are legal or economic.  Copyright is a legal right, not a moral or intellectual right.

You could argue that repositories like ArXiv or open access journals are better than sci-hub because they are more reliable.  But that is not an argument against sci-hub.

Comment: Hmmm. "not a moral ... right". Are you suggesting that creators have no moral claim on their creations nor to benefit fairly from them?

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist Thank you. I also could not come to any convincing arguments on my own, which is why I have posted here. I hope it is ok if I wait for a few more answers. The ones so far have been interesting and helpful. But I do want to say that I appreciate your answer and am probably inclined to agree.

Comment: @Buffy If the "creations" are ideas and not physical objects, then there is no moral right to benefit from them.  As an academic, I don't deal with the creation of physical objects, so I won't go there.

Comment: Also, the true creator is the academic, not the publisher. Yet the copyright is often partially or totally assigned to the publisher. Thus, I personally feel an answer about how the academic is harmed is more convincing than one about harms to the publisher. (For instance, Buffy’s answer discusses how economic harm to the publisher may in turn damage an academic’s ability to publish. And David has proposed an example of a direct harm against the author.)

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist do you consider any of the following physical objects? 1) Music 2) software 3) electronic versions of textbooks?

Comment: @Allure Definitely not.  I'm unclear on how that could even be open for questioning.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist are you saying then that there is no moral right for people to make livings off music/software/ebooks?

Comment: @Allure the comparison to music and software makes an interesting point. There is less incentive to make music if you can’t make a living from it. On the other hand, the analogy with academic publishing is not exact either. Academics do not publish articles primarily to make money.

Comment: @Allure, no, I am saying there is no moral right to the copyright on those things.  There might be a moral right to charge for live performances or to charge for the service of writing sheet music/software/ebooks.  When you buy music recordings or streaming subscriptions, the money goes to the copyright holder, who is usually not the artist.  Artists make most of their money from live performances.

Comment: @richard many musicians don't make music primarily to make money either. It's just that they don't have a choice if they want to put food on the table. The difference is academics don't actually have to monetize the research they do.

Comment: Good point. I didn’t mean to imply that about musicians and others. I was trying to point out that while musicians make money off of music sales, many academics do not make money from publishing. I do understand the point you are trying to make though.

Comment: The comparison between musicians and academics is interesting. Academics are often hired by the state, and producing research papers is part of their job as a civil servant. In some countries, it is even mandatory that this tax-funded content is published open-access. Would the same model work for musicians? The state selects the best musicians via a fair competition, and hires them to produce music that is then distributed for free and available to everyone. Maybe we should try to make musicians work more like academics, not the other way round.

Answer (score 4):

Every journal and conference I've ever published with allows me to post my papers on my personal website and distribute them freely. When SciHub posts my work they are not actually adding any value, as my work is already available for free. Instead, they're breaking copyright law and driving traffic away from my personal website, where interested researchers might find out more about me and what I do.

Comment: So how do I find the papers you’ve put on your personal website? They won’t turn up in regular indexes (the paywalled journaled versions will), and will be lost in the noise on regular search engines. SciHub gives a centralised place to find accessible papers. Seems like added value to me (copyright law not withstanding).

Comment: Well, that's when SciHub posts **your** work :)

Comment: That said, don't be so sure. Even if the preprints you post on your website are text-equivalent to the respective published versions, many readers (especially those who want to cite the published version and thus need to make sure they're citing it correctly) will still want to see the published version, unless you explicitly say that your version is equivalent (which very few academics do).

Comment: This is an interesting answer. Thank you. As I understand it, the motivation is to drive those who can’t afford journal access to turn to your personal website, where they might find not only the paper but more of your research.

Comment: Personal websites are a bit ephemeral. When a person changes jobs, their old websites might be destroyed, leaving dead links.

Comment: @rhialto Google Scholar is very good at picking up PDFs from personal web sites.

Answer (score -3):

Publishing requires money.

If you reduce the amount of money in the system, publishers will lose incentive to publish. That would be bad for authors since publishers, simply by publishing, provide a valuable service to authors as well as others wanting access to scholarly works.

It might be possible to do all of it as a charitable endeavor, but it would still require money. It needn't be a profit making business, but it isn't free (as in beer).

It is also possible to do this as a government (tax) funded operation. But that would bring the possibility of censorship of things that a given government might not want to support; reproductive health comes to mind in the US under the current government.

Online publishing requires *less* money than print, but most of the expenses are still there. It doesn't eliminate the need for money. People still expect to be paid for their efforts. And note that a publisher putting something online is, in effect, promising to keep that server running in perpetuity. Few organizations can make that commitment lightly.

So, the "academic" argument is actually an economic one. If you want something to exist, you need ways to assure that it does.

---

Let me note that if you are a working academic and need access to papers to continue your work, there are zero cost (to you) alternatives that are perfectly accepted and valid. If you ae normally grant funded you can usually charge access and, perhaps, even subscription fees to a grant. If you are not grant funded and your need is sporadic, you can sometimes get a university department to cover your fees. Failing that, you can sometimes contact authors for "preprints" that are often given to them for print journals. And, almost every academic librarian knows how to find copies of almost everything on the planet through inter-library loan. The existence of high fees need not be a block to academic progress.

Comment: It's a valid argument per se, but there's a cost-benefit computation to be made here. The benefit of an available infrastructure doesn't come for free, but costs academics and academic institutions money, either in the form of subscriptions, or of open-access fees. It's perfectly possible that most academic institutions would save money if the majority of the publishing infrastructure was based on a non-profit publishing service financed by networks of academic institutions, rather than relying on external service providers.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper, yes, that might be a viable economic model. There might be several others, but resources are required in any case.

Comment: If there's a viable economic model that lowers the publication-related cost for academic institutions while offering free open access, the economic argument against using Sci-Hub collapses.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper, but not if the use of SciHub still reduces the amount of money to below what is needed. Even your model might require some inputs from subscribers and/or authors. If the cost of running a university increases the funds must come from somewhere. The costs don't, somehow, disappear.

Comment: I'm not sure about that 'commitment' argument. If I have to bet on which one is more likely to keep a server online for the next 50 years between Cornell University and Elsevier, my money goes to Cornell. In addition, it would be easier for someone to make a dump of all Arxiv papers before it goes offline, than to do the same for Elsevier, just because they have to jump through fewer hoops to download them.

Comment: Also, regarding the censorship argument, note that the US government has [already proved](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/trade-sanctions) that they have the power to decide what Elsevier can or can not publish.

Comment: Thank you for writing this answer. It makes sense that if people stop paying for subscriptions, publishers will find it hard to survive. On the other hand, a lot of the users of Sci-hub are those who don’t have the money to pay for the articles in the first place. Are a lot of universities canceling their subscriptions to journals because of Sci-hub?

Comment: @richard, I don't know about that. The current system is far from ideal and it is good that things like open science are exploring options. But many uses of SciHub can also be handled just through inter-library loans from any decent library. Even in poorer countries. But I doubt that uncompensated "taking" is a sustainable solution.

Comment: Good point, thanks. But do you think that interlibrary loan has the same problem? As a substitute, it also seems to decrease profits for publishers.

Comment: @richard, they are actually fine with publishers. It is a long tradition of sharing. It was an easier concept when all published materials were physical and there were no cheap copying mechanisms, but the traditions continue.

Comment: I encourage people not to downvote this answer only because they find it unconvincing. I asked for arguments against Sci-hub, so please only downvote if you find an answer to be low-quality. Otherwise, even answers I disagree with are valuable for my learning.

Comment: -1 for an answer that ignores existing alternatives to the subscription business model. Copyright and paywalls are just one way to fund publishing.

Answer (score -6):

Sci-Hub violates copyright law.

Do you believe in copyright law? I'm certain you use a lot of copyrighted things in your work (e.g. Windows, Google Chrome). When you use a program like Google Chrome, you are supposed to agree with the terms of service. Typically these terms will [include something similar to this line](https://www.google.com/intl/en_pk/chrome/privacy/eula_text.html):

> 9.2 Subject to section 1.2, you may not (and you may not permit anyone else to) copy, modify, create a derivative work of, reverse engineer, decompile or otherwise attempt to extract the source code of the Software or any part thereof, unless this is expressly permitted or required by law, or unless you have been specifically told that you may do so by Google, in writing.

What Sci-Hub does is say "I don't care about this, I'm [taking your program and reverse-engineering it](https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2018/09/18/guest-post-think-sci-hub-is-just-downloading-pdfs-think-again/) anyway, because it is *for the greater good*"*. If we take this to its logical conclusion, then to do research I need to have access to a computer (therefore it should be permissible for me to rob my local computer store), power supply (ditto for siphoning power off the local power grid), and install a pirated version of Windows (my grant is already too small to pay for software licenses, Microsoft already makes billions of dollars in profit anyway). Hell, if I need grant funding to send a space probe to Uranus and NASA rejected my application, I should be allowed to hold the NASA director hostage until he funds me. It's all *for the greater good*.

If you've read the Harry Potter series you might recognize that phrase as the [mantra of the Dark Wizard Grindenwald](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/For_the_Greater_Good).

All that said, it's ultimately up to your personal values and morals. I am against using it entirely, and would not approve of anyone who does.

PS: Here's [a recent question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/144994/advice-needed-on-publishing-a-textbook) by someone looking to make money off a textbook. If the book is published, Sci-Hub is undoubtedly going to pirate it too, because making its information accessible to all is *for the greater good*. Is it? Again, it's up to your personal values and morals.

---

*If you think Sci-Hub is a benevolent entity that only breaks the laws by sharing the files it acquired legally, read the link.

**Edit:**

Tried to access a particular article and ran into this error message:

[image]

Thanks, Sci-Hub. /sarcasm

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I understand, you are saying that following the law is itself of academic value. Otherwise, we should be concerned about people breaking all kinds of laws and social contracts in the name of furthering research and learning. It is dangerous to endorse illegal activity just because it enables some virtuous goals. Is that correct?

Comment: @richard not completely - I believe copyright law is itself justified, and if a jurisdiction didn't have copyright law I would be in favor of implementing it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. So whether a person is against Sci-hub may reflect whether their moral stance on copyright law (as it applies to academic publishing). And you feel that academics should support the existing copyright laws.

Comment: -1 Copyright law is already riddled with exceptions. From the angle of copyright law, the question is whether an exception for academic works would be justified, not whether we should abolish all copyrights.

Comment: Which is still "no", per the PS in the answer. Also, those who want to release their works under a free-to-access license can already do so - just nobody does it.